# Getting issue with date time in swagger UI

Tags: date, time, format, swagger-ui, datetime-format

[image]

I am passing a date-time 31-05-2019 23:59:59 in query string using swagger UI but getting an exception for invalid date-time. Please see attached screenshot.

Answer (score 6):

The DateTime must conform to [ISO-8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) which is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` and therefore you should change the date-time to `2019-05-31T23:59:59Z` before you pass it to the query. Note that `Z` stands for `Zulu` and specifies `UTC+00:00`. If your date-time value has some other zone-offset, specify that in the format, `("+" / "-") time-hour ":" time-minute` e.g. `2019-05-31T23:59:59+05:30` which specifies a date-time with a timezone offset of `5` hours and `30` minutes (India Standard Time).

Given below is an excerpt from [Swagger Data Types](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/):

### String Formats

An `optional` format modifier serves as a hint at the contents and format of the string. OpenAPI defines the following built-in string formats:

- `date` – full-date notation as defined by RFC 3339, section 5.6, for example, 2017-07-21
- `date-time` – the date-time notation as defined by RFC 3339, section 5.6, for example, 2017-07-21T17:32:28Z